# installing jekyll gives returns error (Failed to build gem native extension.)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I have a fresh install of fedora. I installed `ruby`, `ruby-devel` and gone through jekyll troubleshooting on their website but i still get the same error. I tried installing another gem which is `Sass`, just to make sure its not a `ruby` issue and it successfully installed.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/share/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160620-3296-7ascyu.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib64
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1060:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1059:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/ffi-1.9.10/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/ffi-1.9.10/gem_make.out
```

info from `mkmf.log`:

```
package configuration for libffi is not found
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/usr/include -I.    -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -mtune=generic -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L. -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -m64   -lruby  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

PS: I have `ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-linux]`
and `gem 2.6.4` and `ruby-devel-2.2.5-48.fc23.x86_64`

Comment: Have you tried installing development tools first? `xcode-select --install`

Comment: @etagwerker I'm not using OSX.

Comment: Ok, then I would try installing each of the required libraries one at a time, or RVM with autolibs: https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing RVM. it automatically installed Ruby 2.3.0 and then i tried gem install jekyll, and it installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

With CentOS 6 & 7 you can encounter the same issue, even if you have installed ruby && ruby-devel.

To solve this, install gcc & make.